# How to retrieve top 5 results and total count with mongoose and node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the collection with fields as follows,

[image]

i use the following method to query the necessary data,

```
query: function (model, conditon, options) {
            console.log(conditon, options);
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                options = options || {};

                model.find(conditon, {}, options).exec(function (error, data) {
                    if (error)
                        reject(error);
                    resolve(data);
                })
            })
        }
```

How can i change the above to get total count of records and the top 5 elements at once?

Comment: you can just pass limit:5 in our option object like option = {limit:5}

Comment: what about the total count?

Comment: you would require to use aggregate for fetching both count and limited results

Comment: @NaeemShaikh can you show a sample or post answer

Comment: i need to get the total elements which has the search text

Comment: @ShumiGupta any idea ?

Comment: if you want both. Then you can fetch all the data, calculate length of data and use top 5 result of an array. As i don't think this is possible in one query.or you can even run 2 parallel task one calculating the top 5 data other the length

Comment: @ShumiGupta would you mind posting an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregates to get documents and count in the same result.

```
model.aggregate( [
   { $match:conditon},
   { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 }, results:{$push:'$$ROOT'} } },
   { $project: {count:1, results:{ $slice: 5}}}
], function(error, data){
      if (error)
          reject(error);
      resolve(data);
} );
```

Comment: where to pass document name and free text parameter?

Comment: plus 1, still i dont get, do you have a skype id?

Comment: tel me how to call this method

Comment: replace your model.find with above function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137401/discussion-between-naeem-shaikh-and-sajeetharan).

Comment: pls come to the chat

Comment: $$ROOT is not defined

Comment: "message\":\"Expression $slice takes at least 2 arguments, and at most 3, but 1 were passed in.\"}}"}

Comment: try `{ $slice: [0,5]}`

Comment: "First argument to $slice must be an Array, but is of type: NumberInt32\

Comment: when i remove slice i could see only empty array results [{},{}]

Answer (score 1):

```
model.aggregate( [
   { $match: condition } },  // this stage will exclude documents on basis of match
   { $count:"Total Count"}, // this stage gives count of remaining documents after $match
   { $limit: 5} // this will limit your response to 5 documents
], function(error, data){
      if (error)
          reject(error);
      resolve(data);
} );
```

This query will give you result on basis of your condition then counts number of documents and then limit your response.

Comment: it will not count the total documents, but only those documents that match the condition

Comment: yes u r correct i already mentioned it  what u r saying . I think this is the demand of this question.

Comment: @Sam yes right, this is what i want, but am not able to call this method correctly, here is the code dbService.queryaggregate(eventModel, {
                            "$and": [{
                                    "$text": {
                                        "$search": query
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "location.country": country
                                }
                            ]
                        }, {}, 5);

Comment: "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$count'"

Comment: Please note that the $count stage was introduced in MongoDB 3.4. If you would like to make use of this feature, please upgrade.